# How can I resolve my problem with bvad request?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

This is request from front-end

```
const getUsers = async () => {
        const users : any = await axios.get('/api/user/get/users')
        setUsers(users.data)
        console.log(users.data)
    }
 useEffect(() => {
        getUsers()
        
    }, [])
```

This is from back-end

```
    router.get('/get/users', async function(req:any, res:any){
        dbo.collection("users").find({}).toArray(function(err:any, result:any) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(result)
            res.json(result)
        });
    })
```

It`s return 404

Comment: It looks like your API route is not found. What is the host that your API is listening on? It could be a remote server or local port?

Comment: @AJcodez its localhost